# Conditional routing with cntlm

Tags: proxy

I am working in a company where I need a proxy to connect to the internet. I'm currently using CNTLM on Linux and I would like to achieve conditional routing, which means:

1. a request to **serverA** should use **proxy1**
2. a request to **serverB** should use **proxy2**
3. a request to serverI should not use any proxy

Using "NoProxy" configuration I'm able to achieve point 3). How to do 1) and 2) ?

Thanks!

Comment: any luck getting if/else configs?

Comment: unfortunately no :( this doesn't seem to be possible with CNTLM or I didn't found out how